# Failed to load the provider SiloedPackageProvider.dll and metaDeployProvider.dll

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-10-iot-core, dism

Trying to simulate Raspberry Pi in windows 10 laptop with windows 10 IOT Core.

http://annabooks.com/Articles/Articles_IoT10Core/Windows-10-IoT-Core-VM-Version-1.2.pdf

I found this article very useful but has used pre-built image “For MinnowBoard Turbot/MAX”.

I get these errors and other errors too.

Failed to load the provider SiloedPackageProvider.dll and metaDeployProvider.dll

> CFfuMiscHelpersT ValidateNotOnTheSameDisk#904 failed with 0x80070001.

while executing this command from winpe.

Dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"d:\Flash.ffu" /ApplyDrive:.\PhysicalDrive0 /SkipPlatformCheck

Failed to load the provider SiloedPackageProvider.dll and metaDeployProvider.dll

Also please tell me a way to copy logs from the VM running though HyperV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you try to back up a specific library or when you accept the default settings in Windows Backup and Restore.You may try to follow up this [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/973455/windows-backup-or-restore-errors-0x80070001-0x81000037-or-0x80070003#workaroundissue12) to fix the issue.

There are various ways exist to copy data between a Hyper-V host and its guest machines. You can search the ways from internet, or open a new issue for help.

Comment: I am using winpe so just have cmd.

>DIR /AL /S
    volume in drive x is boot
    volume serial number is xxxx-xxxx
File not found

Cant use this.

Comment: Which build of Windows IoT Core and Windows ADK did you test this issue? Currently there is no official introduction about Windows IoT Core run on VM. It is recommended to run Windows IoT Core on  dedicated Hardware.

Comment: ADK - 10.1.17763.1 (Preinstallation Environment)
IOT core - docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/iotcore:1809

Sorry for late response. I understand it is not official doc but it should work right?